# How can I hide an exception type from the output window in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, ide

I'm testing something and the output windows is being flooded with exceptions.

How can I filter an exception type that is shown in the output window.

---

#### Note:

Avoiding exceptions is not possible in this case.

Comment: This is a problem for me too cause I'm catching my exceptions but they still appear in the output. Gets very confusing since now I don't know what I'm trapping and what I'm not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible.  I think you can suppress all exceptions if a certain option is ticked but there is no way to filter the ones that are displayed.

Comment: That's a shame, someone should write an addin for this :)

Answer (score 13):

Hiding an exception type is not possible as I know.
But to filter out all exception messages, right click output window and uncheck "Exception Messages".